# Forecasting future close returns

Tags: time-series, data-analysis

I have end-of-day time-series dataset with following data

```
    Ticker  Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
```

I have calculated end-of-day closing returns (Close_t/Close_t-1) -1 at time t, ratio of High and Low. Each dataset closing returns and High/Low is of size N x p, where  N are dates and p are tickers and N>p. Hence `closing returns` dataset looks like this

`Date  Ticker1  Ticker2 --- until p

  --
  -- 
  --
 until N`
and similarly high/low ratio, where `Ticker` is the company code.
I want to forecast future closing return using any simple model (e.g., Linear Regression). My question is how do I perform analysis with two feature datasets both of size N x p? What will be my final dataset  `X` and labels `y`?

Comment: can't really say without looking at the dataset and output